# How can I parse JSON string from HttpClient?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, httpclient

I am getting a JSON result by calling an external API.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result  = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Fail";
        }
```

The result in line `var s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);` I am getting is like:

```
 {{
  "query": "1",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "1",
    "score": 0.9978111,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": false,
        "name": "1",
        "parameters": []
      }
    ]
  },
  "entities": [],
  "dialog": {
    "prompt": "1",
    "parameterName": "1",
    "parameterType": "1::1",
    "contextId": "11",
    "status": "1"
  }
}}
```

I am using `HttpClient`. I am facing difficulty in accessing `prompt` key-value. I want to get `prompt` from `dialog`. How can I get it?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be doing .Result on client.GetAsync, as this will block the thread.

Comment: OP might not be in a threaded application context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to have a look here:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Create a class with the same structure like your XML. Then your variable `s` is an instance of this class and you can deserialize the json to the class structure.

In your case your property should be `s.dialog.prompt`.

Comment: I guess "XML" mentioned here should be "Json".

Answer (score 45):

There are three ways that come to mind.

1. Assuming the json is consistent and the structure of the response will not change frequently, I would use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or [jsonutils](http://jsonutils.com/) to create c# classes.

   then call:

   ```
   {GeneratedClass} obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<{GeneratedClass}>(result);
   ```

   This will give you a strongly typed object that you can use.
2. You can skip the class generation and use a dynamic object:

   ```
   dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result)
   ```

   and access properties such as:

   ```
   obj.dialog.prompt;
   ```
3. You can use a JObject and access its properties using strings

   ```
   JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

   obj["dialog"]["prompt"]
   ```

Comment: I think in point 3. it should be JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);

Answer (score 14):

Edited :

Import Newtonsoft.Json

```
JObject s = JObject.Parse(result);
string yourPrompt = (string)s["dialog"]["prompt"];
```

Answer (score 5):

By installing the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client like this:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

With:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

you could save one step by directly reading the content as a JObject:

```
dynamic response = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
string prompt = response.dialog.prompt.ToString();
```

Note: This requires the response content to be of Content-Type "application/json".